# Match using directives

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have several classes that I need to format. I need to place the using directives inside the namespace. In other words I have to change:

```
// some comment about system
using System;
using System.Collections.Generics; // needed to create lists

namespace MyNamespace
{
     ... code
```

into:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

     // some comment about system
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generics; // needed to create lists

     ... code
```

*So in short I will like to be able to match:*

```
// some comment about system
using System;
using System.Collections.Generics; // needed to create lists
```

---

what I have worked so far is this regex: `(?s)(//.*?(?=\r))(\r\n|^)*using .*?;`

the first group `(//.*?(?=\r))(\r\n|^)` matches a comment. so if the using has a comment I will like to take that comment also. Note that I placed a `*` at the end of the group in order to have 0 or more comments. for some reason the second using is not matched why?

Comment: Nitpick: these are using *directives*, not using *statements*. The statements are the ones which dispose of resources.

Comment: Great idea thanks. I think that should be an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you where to have something like:

```
// comment goes here
using System.Text.RegularExpressions; // for regexes
using System.Text; /* comment */
using System.Collections.Generic; // som comment
   /* this is a long comment
       that spans multiple lines
       in order to explain this using */
using System.Foo;




namespace EncloseCodeInRegion
{
```

the regex:

```
(((//.*?\r\n)|( */\*[\s\S]*?\*/))?(\r\n)? *using .+?;(( *//.*(?=\r))|( */\*[\s\S]*?\*/))?)(?=[\s\S]*?namespace)
```

would match the all the using statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try regex `(?s)((//[^\n\r]*)\s*?)*((using [^;]+;)\s*?)+`

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a regex? Why not use plain string functions? You only have to find comments and `using` directives before a `namespace`, and move them behind it (and indent, probably).

Something like:

- Read file line-by-line
- If the line starts with `//` (maybe after whitespace), remember it (it's a comment)
- Multi-line comments (`/*` to `*/`) are trickier.
- If the line starts with `using`, remember it
- If the line starts with `namespace`, print it , the print all remembered lines, then print the rest.